# Creating fancy login boxes

Tags: android, android-layout

Android Studio 0.2.11

I am new to android programming and just wondering what I need to do to create a fancy login box like the one below. I am not asking anyone to do it for me. But what sort of controls would I need to accomplice something like this?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

[image]

Comment: In your case you have to use TextView,ImageView,EditText,Button and LinearLayout...

Comment: do you want it to be a pop-up login box?

Comment: @Haresh is right, eveything should be customized.

Comment: All of them are the normal views and you have to customize them with using transparent background..

Comment: @GreenFox, It won't be a popup, it will be just on the layout for the main activity. So when the user starts the app they will see this and enter their details. thanks.

Comment: I would like the design to be the same with the colors and the texture.

Comment: oh in that case it wont be so hard i think, you just needed a few things to be done, learn how to use Linearlayout, create custom buttons and background for edittext.

Comment: @ant2009 here i made something for you, this isnt as fancy as how you want it to be, but i hope it will give you idea. https://github.com/greenfox1101/Android-Projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i am giving you some of the transparent layout with your requirement try to set to the activity with your background..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#60000000"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#40000000"
        android:text="Sign In" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#40000000"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="#40000000"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#40000000"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be acheived easily once you are familiar with linearlayout and relativelayout.

[Here is a cloning of the higlight login screen.](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Cloning-a-Login-Screen-Layout)

This helped me alot in UI design. Hope you too find it usefull.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

- Have an AlertDialog, that you create with an AlertDialog.Builder.
- Title of the 'Sign in'. You dont use an icon..
- In the Builder use `setContentView` for the two EditText widgets and the TextView of 'forgot...'
- You define a positive button. You must get that button once the AlertDialog is created and before you call `show` on it. Once you hwve the button as an Button object, you can decorate it in green etc.
- A last thing: the password EditText must have inputType 'password' and the TextView with 'forgot...' must be clickable so you can react on user clicking on it.